# Empty array model used in dynamic route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

When transitioning to a dynamic route with an empty array as the model, it seems like Ember relates to it as `undefined`.

Thus, if this is the template:

```
{{#linkTo dynamic arrayProxy}}link{{/linkTo}}
```

and this is the route definition:

```
DynamicRoute = Ember.Route.create(function() {
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor("parent").find(params.name);
  },

  serialize: function(model) {
    return { name: model.get("name") };
  }
});
```

when `arrayProxy` is either `[]` or `Ember.ArrayProxy.create(content: [])`,
after clicking on the link: 
the model hook will not get called, of course. 
The serialize hook will get `undefined` as the `model`, no matter that ArrayProxy is a valid Ember object with its own properties.

Does anyone know how to force ember handle empty arrays differently from `undefined`?

Comment: I think that you need to show more code ... Do you have a route called `ParentRoute`? And where is defined the `arrayProxy` property of the template? What is your ember version?

Comment: I'm using Ember 1.0.0.
The serialize hook is called immediately after the template rendered to deduce the linkTo's href. The model hook not get called anyhow, so ParentRoute is not part of the problem.

Comment: You will have to show the code related to your template with the linkTo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake... 
Apparently, the link was nested in the template under the following `if` block:

```
{{#if arrayProxy}}
  {{#linkTo dynamic arrayProxy}}link{{/linkTo}}
{{else}}      
  {{#linkTo dynamic}}link{{/linkTo}}
{{/if}}
```

Since `arrayProxy` is an empty ArrayProxy, the `else` part gets called and the second linkTo is rendered. 
Hence, `DynamicRoute`'s `serialize` hook gets `undefined` as the `model` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if is a typo mistake, but you are missing the return in the model hook:

```
model: function(params) {
  return this.modelFor("parent").find(params.name);
},
```

Without this, the `serialize` will always receive an `undefined` as model variable.

Serialize need the return too:

```
serialize: function(model) {
  return { name: model.get("name"); }
}
```

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, apparently mixed a little coffeescript in my question... :-)
Unfortunately, it's not the problem.